# How to pause currently running process

Tags: c#

I have developed a  socket program . I have the problem with the client side socket program it gets data from multiple servers,one at a time and update the details in listview. It happens inside a infinite loop.

```
while(true) 
{

}
```

I want to exit this this loop in the middle period, I used button click event to do that

```
foreach (Process myProc in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (myProc.ProcessName == "procees name")
    {
        myProc.Kill();
    }
}
```

but it's too slow, I want to pause that process and kill it. Help me to pause currently running process.

Comment: i want to pause the thread and  kill it..I think it will quit this application faster than direct killing

Comment: Killing a process is not the right way to do. Is the process your own process? Or is it a separate application?

Comment: Not a seperate process .If it kills then application will exits.

Comment: @user1776177 Why not try `Application.Exit()` in this case?

Comment: It takes lot of time  to exit thats why i want to pause the process

Comment: @user1776177 Pausing the process was made possible by Cheat Engine, but I do not really know how they did it. Perhaps you'd like to take a look at nawfal's solution. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention the process is your own application, you can just exit the application yourself instead of killing the application. Your question turns out more to be "how can I exit my program".

Firstly, your button may not seem responsive since you're running an infinite loop. One (bad) way of doing it is like this:

```
private bool _exit = false; //member variable
while(true && !_exit) 
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

`Application.DoEvents` is important to make your application keep listening to other actions. And then,

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _exit = true;
}
```

The ideal way imo is to transfer the job of getting data from servers to a background process. May be something like this:

```
BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(); //member field

void Listen()
{
   _backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
   _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   _backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) => { while(condition)//bla bla; }
   _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And then upon your cancellation click,

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}
```

Comment: Why `while(true && !_exit)` and not just `while(!_exit)`? Why testing for negative value at all while you can revert the naming convention and test for positive value and not use the '!'?

Comment: `while(true)` is loop the OP has given. I was adding an additional condition to it. Basically I was trying to tell the OP: "use whatever condition you might like, but add one more". I dont think `while(true)` is in the production code of OP, its more a question asked here. So I was answering on the same line. I dont think its worth a down vote.

Comment: I dont know how much more confusing a `!` symbol can be. If it does for you, I doubt u r a good programmer. My logic is simple. Loop through while till an exit condition is met. Now under the button click I can set: `exit = true` which is rather straightforward. Either way its a trivial topic, even for a down vote :)

Comment: Neither I find it confusing, nor question your programming skills. I was just wondering what is your reasoning behind such syntax. Now I got it, okay. I don't understand this approach however; making things complicated just to 'answer on the same line' instead of keeping it simple. Am I allowed to have my own opinion on this?

Comment: @Aoi, I dont find it "bizarre" as far as syntax goes. It doesnt require any extra brain wracking imo. ymmv

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature to pause running process, so the answer is no.

If this would be possible you could change every process, and that is something which all software builders try to prevent.

You will need some way around.

However, if you have time you can try 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mmehta/multithreading311162005045743am/multithreading3.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2042/Using-events-for-thread-synchronization

Comment: This answer is wrong. Install Process Explorer from www.sysinternals.com and right click a process -> Suspend.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle multiple simultaneous socket connections, I'd suggest using [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.socketasynceventargs.aspx) instead of traditional `while (true)`.

Take a look at this article:

- [C# SocketAsyncEventArgs High Performance Socket Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod)

And the simplest (but not flawless) solution that usually comes with the `while` loop is something like this:

```
private volatile bool _running = true;

...

while (_running)
{
    // Do stuff
}

...

public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _running = false;
}
```

Comment: Actually it does work as long as the `while` loop is not on the UI, but the worker thread. I assumed this is the case from the original question.

Comment: hmmm. since OP was talking about actions getting slow, I thought it could be the UI thread..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application (how many threads, what ui library), you could just use 
[Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx). Perhaps you should set the [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property of your worker threads when creating them.

Just imagine what would happen, if it were possible to pause the process. The user clicks the button, your program pauses the current process, and than there is nothing to do, because you just paused yourself. The code to kill the process would never run.

Answer (score 0):

You could suspend all the threads of a remote process.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2964/Win32-process-suspend-resume-tool